# getting 'UnsatisfiedLinkError' using JNI to pass string from C++ to java w/OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, c++11, java-native-interface

The picture linked below shows the specific exception I'm getting. I'm not quite sure why I'm having this particular issue as I've built everything in the same directory, so the library file is there. From what I understand this has something to do with what I'm returning to my main method from my c++ function.

What I'm essentially trying to do is pass the name (printId) of the recognized person, as a string, from my c++ function to java.

Picture of command line:

[image: Picture of command line]

Here's my C++ code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/face.hpp"
#include "opencv2/face/facerec.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "recognitionJNI.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


String face_cascade_name = "/Users/greg/Downloads/opencv-3.4.2/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
String fn_csv = "/Users/greg/Desktop/faceBuild/faceRecognition/faceRecognition/csv.txt";

//User Defined Function for reading csv
static void read_csv(const string& filename, vector<Mat>& images, vector<int>& labels, char separator = ';') {

ifstream file(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in); //opens file for reading
if(!file) {
    cout << "ERROR: There was a problem loading the csv file" << endl;
}

string line, path, classlabel;
while(getline(file,line)) {
    stringstream liness(line);
    getline(liness, path, separator); //read stream object up to the semicolon
    getline(liness, classlabel);      //read the rest of stream object up to null terminated character

    //make sure that the filepath and userID are not empty
    if(!path.empty() && !classlabel.empty()) {
        images.push_back(imread(path,0)); //appends grayscale image to images vector
        labels.push_back(atoi(classlabel.c_str())); //appends userID to labels vector
      }

   }

}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_testJNIString_userName(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jstring inJNIStr) {

const char *inCStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(inJNIStr, NULL);
if (NULL == inCStr) return NULL;
string outCppStr;

cout << "In C++, the received string is: " << inCStr << endl;
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(inJNIStr, inCStr);

string printId;
vector<Mat> images; //This vector will hold the images
vector<int> labels; //This vector will hold the userID

//read the csv file contain image paths and userID's
try {
    read_csv(fn_csv, images, labels);
} catch (Exception& e) {
    cerr << "Error opening file\"" << fn_csv << "\". Reason: " << e.msg << endl;
    exit(1);
}
//we'll need to resize the images to their origal size
//These two lines capture the length and width of the mat object
int im_width = images[0].cols;
int im_height = images[0].rows;

for(int j=0; j < images.size(); j++) {
    resize(images[j],images[j],Size(im_width, im_height),1.0,1.0,INTER_CUBIC);
}

//int numComponents = 2;
//double threshold = 10.0;

//creats a faceRecognizer to train with given images
Ptr<cv::face::FisherFaceRecognizer> model = cv::face::FisherFaceRecognizer::create();
model->train(images, labels);

string camera_msg = "No camera found";

Mat webcam;             // creates Mat object for to store frames
VideoCapture cap(0);    // opens default webcam
if(!cap.isOpened()) {
    return env->NewStringUTF(camera_msg.c_str());
}

face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name); //loads xml file into classifier

//load capture device into Mat object
while (cap.read(webcam)) {


    vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray; //will be used to store grayscale copy of webcam

    cvtColor(webcam, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY); //coverts Mat object frames into grayscale
    equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);         //maps input distrubution to more uniform distribution


    //locate the faces in the frame
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 5, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE,Size(30,30));

    for(size_t i=0; i < faces.size(); i++) {

        Rect face_i = faces[i]; //process faces by frame
        Mat face = frame_gray(face_i); //takes the face from the live images

        //resize faces for prediction
        Mat face_resized;
        resize(face,face_resized,Size(im_width, im_height),1.0,1.0,INTER_CUBIC);

        int prediction = model->predict(face_resized); //predict based on resize faces

        if(prediction == 1 ) {
            printId = "Matthew";
        }
        else if (prediction == 2) {
            printId = "Greg";
            return env->NewStringUTF(printId.c_str());

        }
        else if(prediction != 1 || 2 ){
            printId = "Unknown";
        }

        rectangle(webcam, face_i, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1); //draws a rectangle around the face
        string box_text = "Prediction = " + printId;

        int pos_x = std::max(face_i.tl().x - 10, 0);
        int pos_y = std::max(face_i.tl().y - 10, 0);

        putText(webcam, box_text, Point(pos_x,pos_y), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1);

    }

    imshow("Webcam", webcam);
    waitKey(1);
    destroyAllWindows();

  }

return env->NewStringUTF(printId.c_str());

}
```

Here's my Java code:

```
public class recognitionJNI{
    static {
    System.loadLibrary("recogjni");
}
    private native String userName(String msg);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String result = new recognitionJNI().userName("Pass arg from c++ function");
    System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try regenerating the header file, it looks like you changed your class name in the meantime and the name is no longer up to date. The name I get from that java class is:

```
Java_recognitionJNI_userName
```

But you have

```
Java_testJNIString_userName
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it! I can't believe I overlooked that.